# How many punctuations are there?

Tags: grammar

most websites say that there are 14 punctuation marks for example ([https://eklavyaparv.com/content/communication-skills/362-punctuation-marks-in-english-grammar#:~:text=Broadly%20speaking%2C%20there%20are%2014,%2C%20quotation%20marks%2C%20and%20ellipses.](https://eklavyaparv.com/content/communication-skills/362-punctuation-marks-in-english-grammar#:%7E:text=Broadly%20speaking%2C%20there%20are%2014,%2C%20quotation%20marks%2C%20and%20ellipses.)) or (https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/what/fourteen-punctuation-marks.html)

however I feel like there are more punctuation marks for instance (https://www.gkbledsoe.com/how-to-use-punctuation-marks/) this website shows 16 punctuation marks? which one is right? which one should I trust? how many punctuation marks are there?

Comment: Other than for curiousity... does it matter?  For example the % symbol might be counted a as an abbreivation, or punctuation  Do you count “ as a different symbol from two ‘ symbols. Is an apostrope ’ different from a single close quote ’ even they they are the same glyph? and are they "punctuation" or not?  Do rare things like "interobang" or "angle brackets" count.  Are there 2, 3, 4 or infinitely many types of "—" dash symbol?

Comment: Use of punctuation marks changes over time. Quotation marks are modern. Previously, the parts of text that were quoted were indicated by other methods. Some marks are used only in specific trades or fields. Asking how  many punctuation marks a language has is more like asking how many words it has than like asking how many letters.

Comment: well if there are so many and each one of them has so many rules then how do people even remember them and use them? is there a way to find out how many are there?